# Oracle installation not available locally still can i use some open oracle DBs exposed for training?

Tags: java, database, oracle, jdbc, cloud

I don't have oracle installation on my local but still want to use someones oracle instance which is available to use through public internet just for practice. 
Can I really think of such possibility ?  Can there be such public cloud based db offerings which can be used by any one for just practice ?

Comment: Oracle DB is free to download and experient with.

Comment: just dont want to download , install and configure schemas all that stuff..if we can save some time managing all that . if ready made available just want to make call to that db to use it ...

Answer (score 0):

I would check AWS (RDS Oracle Standard Edition One). You can create and use an Oracle standard edition one database for free for a certain duration (after that you either have to drop the RDS instance or start paying for it). I believe the usage is for 1 year.

-Jim